# Ruby: class << self; def method VS. def self.method

Tags: ruby, class

My understanding is that:

```
class Example
  class << self
    def my_method; end
  end
end
```

is equivalent to:

```
class Example
  def self.my_method; end
end
```

but is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct :)

Comment: One important (but rarely needed) distinction is that you can define private methods using the `class << self` syntax.

Comment: Possible dup of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964081/class-self-vs-self-method-with-ruby-whats-better), where some interesting points are made.  Note you will need #1 for `attr_accessor :a`, for the class instance variable `@a`.  You could replace `class << self` with `instance_eval do`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another good reason to use `class << self` is when you need accessors on the class level:

```
class Foo
  class << self
    attr_accessor :bar
  end
end
```

Beware that this is often not what you want as it is not thread safe. But that's a design problem. If you need it, you need it.

Answer (score 3):

They are equivalent, but choose the latter for clarity reasons. When you have a class that is many lines long you may miss the class method definition when using `class << self`.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of class << self all methods defined below will be class methods up until the class << self is closed. For a class method at a singular level or multiple ones if you wish you can define the method as self.foo.

```
class Test
    def self.foo
    end

    def bar
    end
end

class Test
    class << self
        def foo
        end
    end
    def bar
    end 
end
```

In both of these cases you will end up with a class method "foo" and an instance method "bar". Both ways accomplish the same thing.