# In Ruby, what is the difference between a class method and a class's singleton method?

Tags: ruby, singleton

I've seen this in code before and I just read about it in The Well Grounded Rubyist by David A. Black, but there are no examples of use cases to help me understand why someone would want to define a singleton method on a class like this:

```
class Vehicle
    class << self
        def all_makes
            # some code here
        end
    end
end
```

How is the above singleton method on a class different than the usual class method like this:

```
class Vehicle
    def self.all_makes
        # some code here
    end
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [class << self vs self.method with Ruby: what's better?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964081/class-self-vs-self-method-with-ruby-whats-better)

Comment: The question is a duplicate, but the answers on that question definitely leave something to be desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yehuda Katz made an excellent writeup of the differences (among other things). You can find that [here](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/15/metaprogramming-in-ruby-its-all-about-the-self/).

To give you a short summary. When you are defining the class, the `self` keyword refers to the class itself. So, when you do `self.method` you are defining a new method on the Person class. Every class has a metaclass, also known as the singleton class, which can be accessed and modified. In the case of `class << self` you are opening up the singleton class and modifying that value. Functionally, the result is the same, but the class being modified is different.

Comment: Good explanation, Max. One small thing.  I've often seen the expression "open a class", though I've never found a definition for that. Isn't more accurate to say that `class << self` causes `self` to be changed to the singleton class?

Comment: "I've often seen the expression "open a class", though I've never found a definition for that." <-- `open a class` simply means do something to a.k.a modify the class.

Comment: The reason it is refereed to as "opening the class" is because everything in between `class << self` and the corresponding `end` modifies the class. Thus, the class is "open" between `class << self` and `end`.