# Ruby - Ensure only one class object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, singleton, instance

I have a Model `Bot` and I would like to ensure that there is only one `Bot` object in my database. I also need to make sure it is persisted and not tampered with.

My original thought was to do this in a migration, one that would follow the `:bots` table migration. It would include a line that is something like:

`Bot.all.size == 0 ? Bot.create! : nil`

Maybe this would prevent the AR object from being messed with in future migrations?

---

BONUS: Would be awesome to be able to have instant and global access to this class object. I was thinking using a `singleton` module in my `Bot` class that way I can always reference `Bot.instance` and have access to that specific object.

---

USE CASE:

I have 4 types of users in my DB and this bot will be the facilitator to delivery role-specific messages to them through our in-app messaging feature.

The `Class Bot` will have a `has_many` association with `BotMessage/bot_messages`. On the `bot_messages` table will be an enum field for `user_role`.

Messages will be created by company admins and stored in these tables because we want them to be viewable at any time by looking at the "conversation" thread between the User and the Bot.

When it comes to only having 1 bot, it's just that. I have no need for an additional `Bot` object. Additionally, since there is only one object it would be nice to be able to have a way of explicitly targeting that object without having to run a query to find it.

For example, unlike `User` where there could be 1000 records and in order to find the specific one you would do something like `@user = User.find_by_email('foo@bar.com')`, doing something like that for the bot would be unnecessary since there is only one record to find. That is what lead me to believe having a `singleton` object may be worthwhile here, so whenever I need to pull up a message for a specific role, I could run `Bot.instance.bot_messages.where(user_role: 1)` or something similar

Comment: It might be helpful to understand what it is you're actually trying to do. For instance, have you considered creating a plain old ruby class with constants instead of a DB record?

Comment: I updated the post to include a Use Case scenario and explanation of my needs.

Comment: It sounds like you need to save the *internals* of your Bot in a table, one row per setting for example, and have the Bot itself as some kind of singleton wrapper for that.

Comment: Did you end up somewhere with this?

Comment: Hey, went with a completely different approach. No need for the singleton since I just went with a simple 1 model approach of `bot_messages` alone.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your Use Case, I see no reason for `Bot` to be a model.

Let's say you have a role called `cool_user` and you want to get all the `bot_messages` for that role, you might do something like:

```
class Bot

  class << self

    def bot_messages(user_role)
      BotMessage.send(user_role)
    end

  end

end
```

As a very thoughtful but potentially anonymous super code monkey notes in the comments, you could also do:

```
class Bot

  def self.bot_messages(user_role)
    BotMessage.send(user_role)
  end

end
```

Which some folks *might* find more readable. IMO, it is a bit of an issue of personal preference.

In either case, you should be able to do

```
Bot.bot_messages(:cool_user)
```

Since, as stated in the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html),

> Scopes based on the allowed values of the enum field will be provided as well.

So, I believe `BotMessage`, with the properly set `enum`, should respond to `cool_user` and return all the `bot_messages` for that role.

You may need to check the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) to get the syntax exactly right.

I believe this should also satisfy your BONUS requirement.

Comment: I haven't looked at the question closely, but defining the instance method `bot_messages` on `Bot`'s singleton class is equivalent to defining `bot_messages` as a class method on `Bot`: `def self.bot_messages...`.The latter may be clearer to some readers.

Comment: Quick search yielded [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964081/class-self-vs-self-method-with-ruby-whats-better) question and answers. It's not clear to me that there is a definitive answer. I consider it a matter of personal preference. However, I may be mistaken.

Comment: Remediated the attribution. Mmm. *Syntactic Sugar...* And, an upvote from you... *cough, cough* I'm packing it in for the day. ;-) Seriously, thank you.

Comment: The answers to your linked question should be required reading. There really is no such thing as a "class method" in Ruby. All methods are just, well, methods defined on a single object or on all instances of a class. `def self.method` is merely a form of *syntactic sugar*. For that reason I think there is an argument for teaching Ruby newbies to initially use `class << self` for defining methods on a class. Later they could switch to `def self.method` if they want. (Readers, jvillian, in his comment above, evidently anticipated this comment.)

Answer (score 0):

A proven solution would be to use an [STI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) on `User` (with a `user_type` column)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
end

class Bot < User
  has_many :bot_messages, foreign_key: :user_id
end
```

Is it what you're looking for ?

Comment: Sandi Metz does a great talk that you can see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OMPfEXIlTVE). At 25:38, she notes that "Inheritance is for specialization". It seems to me that the approach suggested here is a bit of an abuse (I don't mean to say that in a rude way) of the idea of inheritance. IMO, `Bot` is *not* a specialized form of `User`. `Bot` is an entirely different concept from `User`. So, while this might *work* (I'm not sure if it does or doesn't), it seems to me to be down the wrong path. FWIW.

Comment: Of course, inheritance is for specialization.. It's a basic knowledge.. :) My approach is to say that a `Bot` is a kind of `User` (as a facilitator) with specifics (bot messages, name, ACLs, etc..). This is a specialization if we talk from an OOP aspect (Which is the purpose of Ruby). And this is an STI with a 1-to-N relation between `Bot` & `BotMessage` if we talk from a model-oriented aspect (which is the purpose of ActiveRecord). `Bot` can also be an independent model. In my opinion, the fact of making it out the DB break the principle of EDM because `Bot`, as it's descibed, is an entity..

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I don't know what EDM is (other than Electronic Dance Music - which I like quite a lot). Or ACL, either (other than anterior cruciate ligament, which is best left intact). In your approach, how do you enforce the "only 1 `Bot`" requirement? If `User` has fields that are validated both by ActiveRecord and by the database (let's say, for example, gender, given name, family name, email address), then what values do you assign to the 1 `Bot`?

Comment: Oh, and BTW, I agree that `Bot`, as it is described by the OP, is a database entity. As best as I can see, however, there is nothing in the OP's use case that *requires* that `Bot` be a database entity. So, perhaps the OP has an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) on their hands.

Comment: Thanks for the reply too. I like discussion between 2 passionates developers. Actually. EDM stands for Entity Data Model. You can easily ensure that there is only one `Bot` using a simple `before_create` callback.. I agree with you about the STI and the other field validations. So that's why I told you that `Bot` can be an independent model.

Comment: and ACL stands for Access Control List.