# why has_and_belongs_to_many adds class methods rather than instance methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a couple of models

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end
```

and

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

Now why can't i say

```
prod = Product.new
prod.categories << Category.new
```

Why does `has_and_belongs_to_many` adds class methods like `Product#categories<<` while it should have added instance methods ?

How can i make use of these class methods to set associations ?

Comment: That is an instance method. Why do you think it isn't?

Comment: as per this http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many

Comment: Are you getting an error message when you attempt to access them as instance associations?

Comment: yes, undefined method `categories' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fbaa41eb098

Comment: That is fishy, why is it looking on ActiveRecord::Relation and not in your class? That class is used for queries. If you type this two lines of code you gave us on rails console, does it show this error?

Comment: i am using this in a rake task, for whatever it worth

Comment: But not this code you gave us. I suppose that if you test it on console it works just fine. Give us the code that you create or retrieve the Product instance then I can say what is wrong with it.

Comment: This is what the error should look like: **undefined method `categories' for #<Product:0x007fb4e2d3a1f0>** if your association didn't exist.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hgnT5fHD

Comment: Did you create and run a Rails migration to add the corresponding attributes to your tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the error and code you gave me, that is what you are probably missing:

```
prod = Product.new              # This is a Product instance
prod.categories << Category.new # This works

prod = Product.where(name:'x')  # This returns a query (ActiveRecord::Relation) 
prod.categories << Category.new # This doesn't work

prod = Product.where(name:'x').first  # This is a Product instance
prod.categories << Category.new       # This works
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new object (let's say `Product`), you can use the .build method to fill out those associations and call save!

EDIT: here is a good [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5240944/2410268)

Comment: all instances of Product need to have access to the categories means it should be an instance method, but the truth is it is actually a class method. Please re-read the question :)